# Run Outlook macro from desktop shortcut

Tags: vba, windows, outlook

I am trying to run an Outlook 2013 macro from a desktop that I have already made and works good. I would like to be able to copy this shortcut to other coworkers computers as well.

Any idea's since the autorun function is not supported anymore?

Comment: What autorun function?

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop VBScript (`*.vbs`) that uses the Office COM Automation API to run the macro.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim outlook
Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outlook.Run "MacroName"
```

You may need to use `GetObject` instead of `CreateObject`, as well as bringing the Outlook window to foreground.